# Debug my already instanitated nodejs chaincode

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

I have developed Node.js chaincode in dev mode by following these three steps

1. `peer chaincode install -n {} -v {} -p {} -l node`
2. `peer chaincode instantiate -n {} -v {} -c {} -o {} -C mychannel`
3. `peer chaincode invoke  -n {} -v {} -o {} -c{}`

Now each time when i want to edit my Node.js chaincode i have to follow these steps again and again which take so much of time

1. `peer chaincode install -n {} -v {} -p {} -l node`
2. `peer chaincode **upgrade** -l node -n {} -v {} -c {}`
3. `peer chaincode invoke  -n {} -v {} -o {} -c{}`

Is there any shorter way to do debug my node.js chaincode? So that there will be no need to **upgrade** it every time for minor changes.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the `immutable` property of Blockchain, where you can not modify your action. The only way to save time is to carefully test the chaincodes before deploying it to the network.

Comment: If I remember correctly, in dev mode you don't have to go through all the steps. It's the purpose of this mode.